# Local domain is Pinging but not opening in the browser

Tags: networking, apache2, 17.10, virtualhost, hosts

I have setup local domain for example like this

```
mydomain.test
```

Whenever I ping this domain I receive the following

```
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=87 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=88 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=89 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=90 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=91 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=92 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms`
```

But if i try to visit it in chrome I get this:

```
This site can’t be reached mydomain.test’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for mydomain test
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I have used the following shell script to setup everything
[Virtualhost Manage Script](https://github.com/RoverWire/virtualhost)

Comment: It would be super helpful if the guys with thumps down faces can tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add this line in your host file

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.test
```

then ctrl+x then y

then try

Comment: It's already there

Comment: your trying vps or your local pc?

Comment: I'm trying om Local PC

Comment: then its shoud work now i try same code its wock can you post your hosts files ?

Comment: This is my hosts file 
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.0.1 mydomain.test

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost  next this line add this 127.0.0.1 mydomain.test

Comment: The issue is fixed, Sorry @sanjan it wasn't related to the above code, it was because of running the script on opened VPS shell.
Thanks